# Upgrading a 32 bit EC2 instance to a 64 bit instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Can we do this sort of upgrade with an AMI of a 32 bit instance ? I have seen such discussions on sites including stackoverflow, but is it possible nowadays ?

As of now, I think we will have to do everything again (create a new large instance(64 bit) and install all the applications again) ? Is it not the case when there is a change in architecture ?

EDIT :

As an example, I want to upgrade my 32 bit t1.micro instance to large(which is 64 bit). My OS is Linux and I have LAMP and Tomcat/Java on it. What I mean is, I have an AMI of the micro instance so is it possible to create/launch a large instance using it ? or are there any other ways I can do it (so that I can avoid doing all the LAMP, Tomcat/Java set ups again) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you will have to reinstall/reconfigure your apps on a new 64bit instance... there isn't any migration path from 32 to 64 bit architectures...

Comment: Thanks. This is what I think too and in fact I rebuilt everything from scratch on a 64 bit large instance. btw, please post if you see Amazon has implemented any such things.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to have much meaning.  EC2 is an on-demand environment, just spawn an 64 bit server if you want one.  Are you asking how to upgrade a 32 bit OS installation to 64 bit?  That's going to depend on what OS you're using.  If it's Linux, the broad answer is "It can be done, but not automatically".

Comment: Yes, I want to upgrade my 32 bit OS installation to 64 bit and the OS is linux. Is it different for Linux and Windows ? Can you please let me know how I do that for Linux(which is my case) ?

Comment: +1. @user your question is conflating a dozen different issues. Andy is right, you're going about this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem as you and although there might be ways I doubt they are ease enough to waste your time on.  I ended up just reconfiguring my new servers again but there was a major benefit because I am ultra lazy and this time copied all the commands I used and saved them in an install script.

Now because of this install script, it doesn't matter if I use 32 or 64 bit, I just boot up the linux distro of choice and copy my script and run it as all the packages are the same name.

This is probably not the answer your looking for but your easy options are to stick to 64 bit os's from the start or save all your commands(if its not too many run `history` and look at them) then run them via a script.